# Add arrows to the solution trajectories using ode solver?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I have a system of two odes and i want to plot the phase portrait with arrows and clearly representing the stable and unstable steady states. The problem is that i am getting the solution trajectories but without arrows. So it is very difficult to see which steady state is stable. Here is the ode system:

```
function dy = twodim(~,y, mu, d1, d2, K, n, p, sigma1, sigma2)

dy(1,1) = mu.*((y(1) + y(2)).^n)./(K.^n + (y(1) + y(2)).^n) - d1.*y(1) - y(1).*(sigma1 - sigma2.*(y(2)./(y(1) + y(2) + 1e-12))) ;

 dy(2,1) = y(1).*(sigma1 - sigma2.*(y(2)./(y(1) + y(2) + 1e-12))) - (p + d2).*y(2);
```

Below is the part of the code I use to draw the solution trajectories:

```
mu = 2000;
K = 27000;
d1 = 0;
d2 = 0;
sigma1 = 0.25;
sigma2 = 0.75;
p = 0.24;
n = 1;

close all; hold on
for a = 0:5250:15000
for b = 0:5250:15000
[t, y] = ode45(@(t,y)twodim(t,y, mu, d1, d2, K, n, p, sigma1, sigma2), 0:0.2:15000, [a; b]);
plot(y(:,1), y(:,2))
end
end
hold off
axis([0 15000 0 15000])
```

Comment: Sure! Here it is 

\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{x_h}&=&\mu g(x_h+x_f)-d_1 x_h-x_h\left(\sigma_1-\sigma_2\frac{x_f}{x_h+x_f}\right)\label{2d:xhode}\\
\dot{x_f}&=& x_h\left(\sigma_1-\sigma_2\frac{x_f}{x_h+x_f}\right)-(p+d_2)x_f \label{2d:xfode}
\end{eqnarray}
where $g(x_h+x_f)=\frac{(x_h+x_f)^n}{K^n+(x_h+x_f)^n}$

Comment: @amzoti: which tool did you use?